# Проблема с внесением формы в бд django

Tags: python, django

Пишу приложение с картой столов
Имеется проблема с внесением данных в бд через форму в django

models.py

```
class Table(models.Model):
    table_id = models.IntegerField('Id', primary_key=True)
    max_places = models.IntegerField('Максимальное кол-во мест', default=6)
    price = models.IntegerField('Цена', default=6000)
    busy = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateForm(forms.Form):
    max_places = forms.IntegerField()
    price = forms.IntegerField()
    busy = forms.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        model = Table
        fields = ['max_places', 'price', 'busy']
```

views.py

```
def update(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UpdateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            cd = form.cleaned_data

            pc = Table(
                max_places=cd['max_places'],
                price=cd['price'],
                busy=cd['busy'],
            )
            pc.save()

            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            return redirect('tables-main-2')
    else:
        form = UpdateForm()
```

Выдаёт ошибку **IntegrityError at /tables/331/update**

**NOT NULL constraint failed: table_table.places**

Comment: вы миграции не забыил сделать, а то ошибка не подходит для модели. То есть не вижу поля `places`

Comment: я стёр это поле из вопроса, тк подумал что это лишняя информация. Но сейчас заметил что проблема именно в этих полях. Но всё так же не могу понять как правильно сохранять форму. В форму нужно включать абсолютно все столбцы из бд?

Comment: добавьте все в вопрос нажав, [edit] под самим вопросом. Иначе вы не получите релевантного ответа и это будет гаданием

Comment: Разобрался с сохранением, но не так написал вопрос, мне нужно обновление данных 

Comment: исправьте вопрос)

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил, но немного не до конца

если нужно создать НОВУЮ запись, нужно указать все поля, какие есть в файле   models.py

forms.py

```
class Table(models.Model):
    table_id = models.IntegerField('Id', primary_key=True)
    num = models.CharField('Стол', max_length=3)
    places = models.IntegerField('Кол-во мест')
    max_places = models.IntegerField('Максимальное кол-во мест')
    low_price = models.IntegerField('Цена')
    price = models.IntegerField('Цена агента/промо')
    coord = models.CharField('Координаты', max_length=256)
    busy = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py

```
def update(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UpdateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            cd = form.cleaned_data

            pc = Table(
                num='123'
                places=123
                max_places=123
                low_price=123
                price=123
                coord='123'
                busy=True
            )
            pc.save()
```

Ввести значения можете уже с формы